# How to extract data from an ics file by colsfusion?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012, coldfusion-11

I am new to **Coldfusion**. i am working on an email template in which i need to upload an ics file and then extract the information of that file using coldfusion. and also i want to create an ics file using dynamic data.
how can i extract data from ics file and how can we create an icf file using data.
i searched about this but could not find a specific answer. Thanks

my ics file looks like this

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Test VTF
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Asia/Karachi
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20181115T180000Z
DTEND:20181115T190000Z
DTSTAMP:20181112T154513Z
UID:3k6frbl4bqnebdh1obi42pocnq@google.com
CREATED:20181112T154449Z
DESCRIPTION:Vein Clinics of America California Appointment USA
LAST-MODIFIED:20181112T154449Z
LOCATION:VTF Location USA
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Vein Appointment Conf Nov 
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: ICS files are unstructured text files, so there is no in-built function to turn them into usable data (and back to ICS). But they are text files and do have set data field names (e.g. DTSTART). A very basic way is to upload the ics with cffile and use string search to find the data field names and values you need.

You could also have a look at: https://github.com/dkimbell13/cf_ics_parser

Writing an ICS is just like writing a text file, you just have to get the data field names right and and time/timezone values to match expectations.

Comment: thanks Dom Robinson.
But i am confused. actually i have to open the attachment (ics) into google, outlook and yahoo calendar. i have a button in email Add to calendar. by clicking on specific option, icf should open in calendar. How can i give reference of that attached file to calendars. i am little bit confused. i don't want to download the ics.